# Sending a message using JMS

Tags: java, c++, jms, activemq-classic

I am having a very strange problem with **JMS**.

I have two machines **A-Windows**, **B-Linux**.
**Machine A** initializes JMS (creates one producer and one consumer). (**Java code**)

**Machine B** sends a message to **machine A**. **Machine A** receives! the message and sends a response back to **machine B**. (**C++ code**)

My problem is this : when I run the **machine A** code all is working fine!. BUT when I run the same binary on another windows machine (Lets call it **machine C**) the message from **machine B** is accepted but **machine C** does NOT send the answer.

I sniffed the network and found that in case of **machine A** it sends **TCP-ACK** followed by **TCP PSH-ACK** (with the correct response). BUT **machine C** only sends the **TCP-ACK** **without** the **TCP-PSH-ACK**.

**EDIT :**
Using JConsole I noticed that **machine C**'s out topic attribues : DequeueCount, DispatchCount, Enqueue Count are all zeroes. Seems like the producer is not sending/en-queuing anything (no exception is thrown).

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the solution is so obvious and I am a bit embarrassed for not noticing it. Anyway it seems that the code that ran on **Machine A** used a **non-transaction** session while the code on **machine C** used a **transaction** session without **COMMITING**!!!!.

So I turned the session's transaction flag off (as it fits my needs anyway) and it works like a charm !

About the dude who made changes in code without committing to the svn .... I'll talk with him later :)